# Prevent wifi from disabling at suspend?

Tags: wireless, suspend, xbmc, wakeonlan

I have setup my ubuntu laptop as my XBMC centre, however I am wanting to store it under the TV to keep it tidy, this in turn will make it a faf to get to the laptops power button.

I have already setup my laptop to be able to wake on both U and G, however For whatever reason it isn't working properly.

Is there any way to prevent the network card from shutting down when I suspend my laptop? If I can manage this then I should be able to wake it with my YATSE remote app.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Rob

Comment: What is "U", "G" and "F"?

Comment: U is Unicast and G is for Magic Packet activity. Theu are various options used by ethtool in the terminal.

Comment: I'm to lazy to post this as an answer so here's just a link with a work-around: http://www.webupd8.org/2013/01/fix-wireless-or-wired-network-not.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply but unfortunately this wasn't what I was after, surprisingly I haven't had any on the problems where my wifi wont work after it is suspended. The basic jist of what I was wondering is - Is it possible to tell ubuntu to still direct power to the wireless card even when it is suspended. This is so that I can power it back up using a wake on wireless lan command.

Comment: -1 for using so much jargon when you want help.

Comment: My WiFi just reconnects when it comes out of suspend, all by itself.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible with WiFi - suspend mode means the cpu is halted and the system uses power only to maintain the contents of RAM - or (depending on your settings) to listen on the ethernet port.

Comment: My WiFi just reconnects when it comes out of suspend, all by itself.